# Make folders' last modified date correspond to last modified date of its child folders/files

Tags: date, date-modified, directory-listing

I am working with FileZilla to locate the last modified files of my website.
I thought the last modified date of a parent folder will correspond to the latest last modified date of its children files and folders, but apparently it's not working that way.

Why the last modified date of `components`, of `com_content` and of `views` don't correspond to the one of their child file `edit.php`?

Is it possible to set the a folder last modified date to the last modified date of its child folders/files?

**For example:**
for the file components/com_content/views/form/tmpl/edit.php  (the last modified file on my website)

```
edit.php     last modified date is: 2014-11-23 
tmpl         last modified date is: 2014-11-23
form         last modified date is: 2014-06-22
views        last modified date is: 2014-06-22
com_content  last modified date is: 2014-06-22
components   last modified date is: 2014-07-07
```

`tmpl` contains 3 files (last modified date are 201-06-11, 2014-06-11, 2014-11-23)
`form` contains the folder `tmpl` + 3 more files (last modified date are 201-06-11, 2014-06-11, 2014-07-25)
`components` last modified date correspond to one of it's subfolder `com_akeeba` (all the files/folders in there have the same last modified date).

Answer (score 1):

On most (possibly all) operating systems, a folder (as a list/container of references to files) is modified for example by:

- adding file
- removing file

But **not** by modifying contained files, as that does not change the "list of references to files".

To achieve what you want, you can for example write a cron/scheduler job to update a folder timestamp to a time of the newest contained file.

Comment: Doe anyone has something already made? I am interested in updating the .hg and .git directory timestamps based on when they where updated last time (pushed to).